# Deleting Non Matching Cells

Tags: excel

Another simple one I am hoping from a excel novice!

I have a sheet of data which has two lots of data. Some will have one matching field. I want to sort these so the pairs sit together and the eliminate all data that doesn't have a matching cell.

My explanation was useless so on the kind advice of Slai, I have attached a screenshot of what I hope to achieve:

[image]

```
Many thanks in advance
```

Comment: Sorry, complete typo. Should read 23.

Comment: now corrected, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function next to the data to help you sort or filter it. For example if the supplier names are in separate cells in column A, then to find out how many times each Supplier is found in column A:

```
= CountIf( A:A, A1 )
```

For a better example you can post a screenshot with sample data, because it is not clear from your examples what values are in what column.